# How to add a column to a Spark DataFrame where each new element depends on a groupby of another column?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe in this form:

```
+----------+-----+-------+-------+
| timestamp|  lat|    lon|user_id|
+----------+-----+-------+-------+
|1511512345|34.12|-120.12|      1|
|1511512348|34.13|-120.13|      1|
|1511512349|34.14|-120.14|      1|
|1511551234|31.11|-122.01|      2|
|1511551236|31.15|-122.03|      2|
+----------+-----+-------+-------+
```

and I need to perform a computation on the timeseries of location data per user. The computation requires having the entire timeseries of lat/lon data for map matching (i.e. finding the optimal mapping of GPS locations to a map of roads). The result is a series of `road_id`s that I'd like to then append to the dataframe

```
+----------+-----+-------+-------+-------+
| timestamp|  lat|    lon|user_id|road_id|
+----------+-----+-------+-------+-------+
|1511512345|34.12|-120.12|      1|     12|
|1511512348|34.13|-120.13|      1|     12|
|1511512349|34.14|-120.14|      1|    345|
|1511551234|31.11|-122.01|      2|    737|
|1511551236|31.15|-122.03|      2|    643|
+----------+-----+-------+-------+-------+
```

Note that I need the entire timeseries for each `user_id` together in order to perform this computation (i.e. the computation can not be done row-by-row, but requires the whole group by each `user_id`) How could this be done with the spark dataframe API? I'm not sure whether it is possible to use `groupby` and `withColumn` or some other ways to accomplish this.

```
df.sortby('timestamp').groupby('user_id').agg(...) ?
```

---

The `road_id` sequence is typically computed using an HMM model and is a function of the road network and the entire lat/lon sequence (as described in [Matching GPS traces to a map](http://blog.mapbox.com/matching-gps-traces-to-a-map-73730197d0e2)).

Basically, the input to the map matcher would be the entire sequence of lat/lon values, and the output would be a sequence of road_id values of the same length

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a groupby to generate a new DataFrame, then you join this new DataFrame with the original one.

Answer (score 0):

I use Scala (so YMMV given you tagged it with [pyspark](/questions/tagged/pyspark)).

---

My understanding is that you want to compute a value for every record in a dataset per `user_id` and entire `lat`/`lon` sequence.

That looks to me as a window aggregation problem.

Let's define a window specification (again I'm using Scala so YMMV).

```
val input = Seq(
  ("1511512345", 34.12, -120.12, 1))
  .toDF("timestamp", "lat", "lon", "user_id")

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val byUserId = Window.partitionBy("user_id").orderBy("timestamp")

val inputWithLatsAndLonsCols = input
  .withColumn("lats", collect_list("lat") over byUserId)
  .withColumn("lons", collect_list("lon") over byUserId)
scala> inputWithLatsAndLonsCols.show
+----------+-----+-------+-------+-------+---------+
| timestamp|  lat|    lon|user_id|   lats|     lons|
+----------+-----+-------+-------+-------+---------+
|1511512345|34.12|-120.12|      1|[34.12]|[-120.12]|
+----------+-----+-------+-------+-------+---------+

// define UDF to do the calculation
// NOTE that the UDF always returns 1 for demo purposes
val roadId = udf { (lats: Seq[Double], lons: Seq[Double]) => 1 }

val roads = inputWithLatsAndLonsCols.withColumn("road_id", roadId($"lats", $"lons"))
scala> roads.show
+----------+-----+-------+-------+-------+---------+-------+
| timestamp|  lat|    lon|user_id|   lats|     lons|road_id|
+----------+-----+-------+-------+-------+---------+-------+
|1511512345|34.12|-120.12|      1|[34.12]|[-120.12]|      1|
+----------+-----+-------+-------+-------+---------+-------+
```